# Objective-C how to disable user interaction selectively

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a Main View Controller that has many subviews. What I want is to disable all other views except one subview and its subviews programmatically from the subview file. But all I get is all frozen views. What did I do wrong?

I tried this code:

```
#define kDontDisableUserInteraction 321


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    NSLog(@"initWithFrame");
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.tag = kDontDisableUserInteraction;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)something{

    MVC *myController = [self getMVC];

    for (UIView* subview in myController.view.subviews) {
        NSLog(@"subview.tag %i", subview.tag);
        if (subview.tag != kDontDisableUserInteraction){
            subview.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        }
    }


    for (UIView *view in self.subviews){
        NSLog(@"enabled!");
        view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
}

- (MVC *)getMVC {
    Class vcc = [MVC class];    // Called here to avoid calling it iteratively unnecessarily.
    UIResponder *responder = self;
    while ((responder = [responder nextResponder])) if ([responder isKindOfClass: vcc]) return (MVC *)responder;
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Based on your code above, that 'one subview' is your actual view class

Comment: @Rohan Yes, I want to disable all subviews under the parent view controller, because this object is small and other buttons etc. are still visible, so that is why I want to disable them when this small object appears on the main view.

Comment: I see, looking at your code, I do not see where it goes wrong...

Comment: Can you put an NSLog(); in the subview.tag != kDontDisableUserInteraction condition and see if it gets called

Comment: @Rohan Exactly, but all objects including objects on this subview are frozen. I cannot see why it happens.

Comment: @Rohan It gets called four times. And all tags are zero, which is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by applying a full screen of a button on all other views and get the one view that I want to have user interaction upon the button. This way I disallow the user to click on any function except the one view I want the user to click on certain functions.

Answer (score 2):

Following links may be helpful:

[How to disable touch input to all views except the top-most view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404856/how-to-disable-touch-input-to-all-views-except-the-top-most-view)

[UIView -- "user interaction enabled" false on parent but true on child?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887305/uiview-user-interaction-enabled-false-on-parent-but-true-on-child)

Comment: I have virtually tested all codes provided in these links, but all I get is either all frozen views or all objects are clickable.