# How child view will identifie set property of parent view (iPhone)?

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, user-interaction, uiresponder

The scenario is like,

I have one `UIButton` in one `UIView`.
    So `UIView` is parent view
    and `UIButton` is child view.
Now,

1. If I set user interaction false for parent view then can I click
   `UIButton` ?
2. If I am not able to touch `UIButton` then why `UIButton` is not
   touchable?

Can you explain how `UIButton` will know it's parent view's user interaction is false?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Similar question, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887305/uiview-user-interaction-enabled-false-on-parent-but-true-on-child)

1. No, you can't. userInteractionEnabled set to NO on a parent view will prevent to all subviews.
2. Here is the documentation from Appel about "Event Delivery", check the [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/EventsiPhoneOS/EventsiPhoneOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW1)
3. Check the property `self.superView.userInteractionEnabled` in `hitTest:withEvent:` method or `pointInside:withEvent:` method.