# How to stop a UIButton from being clicked when there is a UIImageView in front of it on iphone?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, uibutton

I am making an Iphone game, and I would like a button to stop being clickable when the character moves in front of it.  Do you know how this can be done?

Comment: i mean like how to make it so something behind a UIImageView is unclickable through the UIImageView.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427619/disable-touches-on-uiview-background-so-that-buttons-on-lower-views-are-clickabl

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify button's frame whenever character enters. As soon as they hit the frame you need to do  `[button setEnabled:NO]`;